# Subtract first and last element (wrap around) in numpy diff

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large 100000,6 array and would like to find the diffence to the each element in the vector. np.diff is almost exactly what I need but also want it to wrap around and it also finds the differnce in the first and last element.

Toy model:

```
array=np.array([[0,2,4],[0,3,6]])
np.diff(array,axis=1)
```

gives
`[[2,2],[3,3]]`
would like to have `[[2,2,-4],[3,3,-6]]` or `[[-4,2,2],[-6,3,3]]`

Is there a built in way in numpy to do this?

Comment: you can just use `np.hstack` to append the rightmost values manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
np.roll(array, -1, axis=1)-array
```

Output:

```
array([[ 2,  2, -4],
       [ 3,  3, -6]])
```